# Facebook API - How to get user's nationality (location)?

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm using Facebook Phonegap plugin for my mobile game project. My problem is I can't get user's location after call `facebookConnectPlugin`:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"], function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.authResponse.userID));
    sessionStorage.setItem("userID", JSON.stringify(response.authResponse.userID));
    facebookConnectPlugin.api(
        "me/?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name,location", ["user_birthday"],
        function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response))
        }, function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response))
        });
    $state.transitionTo('app.home');
}, function(response) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response))
});
```

facebookConnectPlugin.js

```
/*
 * @author Ally Ogilvie
 * @copyright Wizcorp Inc. [ Incorporated Wizards ] 2014
 * @file - facebookConnectPlugin.js
 * @about - JavaScript interface for PhoneGap bridge to Facebook Connect SDK
 *
 *
 */

if (!window.cordova) {
// This should override the existing facebookConnectPlugin object created from cordova_plugins.js
    var facebookConnectPlugin = {

        getLoginStatus: function (s, f) {
            // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
            try {
                FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                    s(response);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    f(error.message);
                }
            }
        },

        showDialog: function (options, s, f) {

            if (!options.name) {
                options.name = "";
            }
            if (!options.message) {
                options.message = "";
            }
            if (!options.caption) {
                options.caption = "";
            }
            if (!options.description) {
                options.description = "";
            }
            if (!options.link) {
                options.link = "";
            }
            if (!options.picture) {
                options.picture = "";
            }
            
            // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
            try {
                FB.ui({
                    method: options.method,
                    message: options.message,
                    name: options.name,
                    caption: options.caption,
                    description: (
                        options.description
                    ),
                    link: options.link,
                    picture: options.picture
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (response && response.request) {
                        s(response);
                    } else {
                        f(response);
                    }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    f(error.message);
                }
            }
        },
        // Attach this to a UI element, this requires user interaction.
        login: function (permissions, s, f) {
            // JS SDK takes an object here but the native SDKs use array.
            var permissionObj = {};
            if (permissions && permissions.length > 0) {
                permissionObj.scope = permissions.toString();
            }
            
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    s(response);
                } else {
                    f(response.status);
                }
            }, permissionObj);
        },

        getAccessToken: function (s, f) {
            var response = FB.getAccessToken();
            if (!response) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error("NO_TOKEN");
                } else {
                    f("NO_TOKEN");
                }
            } else {
                s(response);
            }
        },

        logEvent: function (eventName, params, valueToSum, s, f) {
            // AppEvents are not avaliable in JS.
            s();
        },

        logPurchase: function (value, currency, s, f) {
            // AppEvents are not avaliable in JS.
            s();
        },

        logout: function (s, f) {
            // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
            try {
                FB.logout( function (response) {
                    s(response);
                })
            } catch (error) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    f(error.message);
                }
            }
        },

        api: function (graphPath, permissions, s, f) {
            // JS API does not take additional permissions
            
            // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
            try {
                FB.api(graphPath, function (response) {
                    if (response.error) {
                        f(response);
                    } else {
                        s(response);
                    }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                if (!f) {
                    console.error(error.message);
                } else {
                    f(error.message);
                }
            }
        },

        // Browser wrapper API ONLY
        browserInit: function (appId, version) {
            if (!version) {
                version = "v2.0";
            }
            FB.init({
                appId      : appId,
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : version
            })
        }
    };
    
    // Bake in the JS SDK
    (function () {
        console.log("launching FB SDK")
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());

}
```

Comment: Did you ask for the necessary permission during login …?

Comment: nope, I just can't get location value. thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't ask for the appropriate permission `user_location`, and if you don't, you can't get access to the data. That's plain simple.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/#readperms

Comment: Replace first row with `facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email", "user_location"], function(response) {`

Comment: As you don't have any references what `facebookConnectPlugin` does, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Well, *still not working* is also maybe not the best way to describe an error. I will not invest any more time in this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist